# Ajax request in cordova application's

Tags: cordova

I'm using cordova.I want to use $.ajax jquery request in my app.This is my "Content-Security-Policy" meta tag :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src 'self' http://localhost">
```

I have a link in my app :

```
<div data-role="page" id="login_page" data-theme="a" >
            <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                        <button data-role="button" id="get_web_data" data->icon="lock" data-transition="fade" >Get Web data</button>
            </div>
        </div> <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery_2.1.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="rtl-jquery-mobile-master/js/rtl.jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js"></script>
```

And this is my jquery code :

```
 $('#get_web_data').on('tap',function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'http://localhost/test.php',
            type:'GET',
            data:{'user_name':'amir','password':'123'},
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(data){
                alert(data);
            },
            error:function(error){alert('Error');}
        }) ;
     });
```

After click on the link I see this error :

> index.html:1 Failed to load
>   http://localhost/test.php?user_name=amir&password=123: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Where is my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the first line of the PHP file. `header('Access-control-allow-origin: *')`

Check [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) for more detail. Basically the request is not trusted by the server and so it denies. By setting up the CORS you allow all requests

Answer (score 0):

I changed the script.js file and every thing works now.

```
$('#get_web_data').on('tap',function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'http://localhost/test.php',
            type:'GET',
            data:{'user_name':'amir','password':'123'},
            dataType:'json',
            timeout: 5000,
             crossDomain: true,
              error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('new textStatus=' + textStatus + ' errorThrown=' + errorThrown);
            },
            success: function (response) {alert(response);
    }
        }) ;
     });
```